# QGIS 3 Polygon based on points

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I have a point shapefile and want to create a polygon shapefile that intersects all the points.

For instance:
- Point shapefile with 4 points (representing a square area);
- Want to automate the process of creating a polygon that intercepts the 4 points forming the square;

Since I need precision, automating the process will garantee that each polygon vertice is on the exact position.

On QGIS 2.x I used a plugin named Points2One which is not available for QGIS 3.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of a Group constisting of more than four points?

Answer (score 2):

A common (somewhat *quick and dirty*) way is to derive the *Minimum Bounding Geometry*, or the *Convex Hull* for a given set of geometries. Both tools can be found in the *Vector Geometry* menu in the *QGIS Toolbox*.
*Minimum Bounding Geometry* offers more options, e.g. to specify a field to group the layer´s features and multiple bounding geometry types (incl. *Convex Hull*).

Both tools will, however, connect the outermost vertices with a straight line. If you want to get closer to a concave/true shape of the combined features, try the *Concave Hull* tool. In all cases, an exact connection between all outer vertices will likely not be achieved for complex shapes.